# Anchor tag follows url even after doing element.preventDefault() in jQuery Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to delete an element with jQuery. EVerything works fine but for some weird reasons, even after doing element.preventDefault() in script, anchor tag follows href after deleting goal and gives ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error. I understand that record has been deleted so it is giving ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error after trying to open up that page. But I don't understand what else I can do to stop it from vising any page.

```
<% if current_user == @habit.user %>
  <% habit_id = @habit.id %>
  <% goal_id = goal.id %>
  <a href="/habits/<%= habit_id %>/goals/<%= goal_id %>" data-confirm="Destroy <%= goal.name %>?" data-method="delete" class="jquery-postback" rel="nofollow">Delete Goal</a>
<% end %>



<script>
$(function() {
$(".jquery-postback").on('click', function(element) {
    element.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    $.post({
        type: $this.data('method'),
        url: $this.attr('href')
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert('success');
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried to play a lot with script and anchor tag but couldn't find any solution. Any suggestion to solve this error?

ps: this functionality allows user to delete goal from the habit show page.

Comment: Try wrapping your click event listener in a DOMContentLoaded callback `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) { 
  $('.jquery-postback').on('click', function(element) {
    ...
  })
})`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SebastiánPalma, tried this, it doesn't divert but it doesn't delete through jQuery. It is using rails. I can see page refreshing. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. If anyone else is having the same problem, if you rewrite anchor tag without data-method="delete"  and rel="nofollow" it would work.

Something like this....

```
<a href="/habits/<%= habit_id %>/goals/<%= goal_id %>" data-confirm="Destroy <%= goal.name %>?" class="jquery-postback" >Delete Goal</a>
```

The reason behind is, Rails comes with some helpers that create event handlers for all the "delete" actions generated by Rails. This is the JQuery code that Rails uses:

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

So, the event handler will be the only one executed if anchor tag is without data-remote and data-method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class with `pointer-events: none` for disabled links:

```
.disable-link{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And apply this class to the element.

Comment: Thanks a lot @archana for your suggestion. But after adding this, delete link is kind of like a plain text, can't do anything. Any other suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: How would you like to see the link after the link is clicked?

Comment: Thanks for your time Archana, after link is clicked, I want it to delete goal from the database.

Comment: But what should happen to the link? How should it look or behave after it's been clicked?

Comment: Hey Archana, link should completely disappear after it is clicked once. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In that case you can use `display: none` css property.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$("a.jquery-postback").on('click', function(element) {
  element.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

Not sure why, but you need to target specifically the `a` link tag for `.preventDefault()` to work.